# regular expression for just number with fixed length and without digit back or front occurred that and without use \b

Tags: python, regex

I want regular expression for just number with fixed length and without digit back or front occurred that without using \b
sample text: "phone0990-123-12345hello"

my regex: `r'09([0-9]){2}([ ]|-){0,1}([0-9]){3}([ ]|-){0,1}([0-9]){4}(?:[^0-9])'`

this regex must return null but it return 0990-123-12345 for me!
I say to it match numbre in text that don't continues digit after 9 target digit with (?:[^0-9]) and with ?: say to it that don't show non digit in match. I don't want show h character in match!

Comment: add anchors `^`, `$` or word boundaries or spaces inside lookaheads and lookbehinds

Comment: Can you give more examples about what you want to do? For the example you give you can just use `'09\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}'`. Are there cases where you don't have dashes (`-`)?

Comment: I correct my gold. I want that regex don't return anything for number similar example

Comment: To clarify: if there's an additional number of the "0990-123-1234" string, the whole thing does not quality as a phone number? That is, "phone0990-123-1245hello" does not contain a phone number?

Comment: The key here is *not enclosed with digits*: `(?<!\d)....your_pattern...(?!\d)`.

Comment: thanks. (?<!\d)....your_pattern...(?!\d) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As you give the exact number of digits with `{4}`, you can just leave the part `(?:[^0-9])` out.

Summing up, this regex works for me:
`r'09([0-9]){2}([ ]|-){0,1}([0-9]){3}([ ]|-){0,1}([0-9]){4}'`

You can check your regular expressions on:
https://pythex.org/

Comment: I correct my gold. I want that regex don't return anything for number similar example

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to understand the question ,but you could also try

```
09([0-9]+){2}([ -]+){0,1}([0-9]+){3}([ -]+){0,1}([0-9]){4}
```

Comment: I correct my gold. I want that regex don't return anything for number similar example

Answer (score 0):

try

```
\d{4}[-.]\d{3}[-.]\d{4}
```

it will return 0990-123-1234

Comment: I correct my gold. I want that regex don't return anything for number similar example

Answer (score -1):

Try `r'\d{4}\-\d{3}-\d{3,4}'` it will return only **0990-123-1234**

Comment: I correct my gold. I want that regex don't return anything for number similar example

Comment: @UserN030,please use code tags for your codes/samples in your posts.